# relationship 3 table in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

i have 3 table

Table Post

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->text('title');
$table->longText('description');
```

Table User

```
 $table->increments('id');
 $table->string('username',30)->unique();
 $table->string('email')->unique();
```

Table Comment

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->longText('comment');
$table->integer('user_id');
$table->integer('post_id');
```

I want to Show Post Page in footer, I want show comment by username

What can i do to relation it in laravel 5.4. Please Help explain with code.

thank for you answer.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships has the exact same 3 table and model relationship in all of its examples. This is not a create your source code site. You need to at least try before you seek help.

Answer (score 3):

for more information you should go and check https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships that's so efficient and simple for working with multiple table without involving join in sql.

especially for your tables this documentation has good example and i am sure you will get your answer.

best regard!

Comment: I have use `hasMany` to get it. but in comment i get only user_id.I has query `select * from posts,comments,users where post.comment_id = comment.id and comment.user_id = user.id`.But i want to use relation in model. How could i do this?